# No Neighbor Vertex Cover

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, optimization, dynamic-programming, np-hard

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected connected graph with a set of vertices $|V|$ and a set of edges $|E|$. A set cover $D$ satisfies $D \subseteq V$ and $uv \in E \implies u \in D \lor v \in D$. A variant of the vertex cover requires that **exactly one vertex**, $u$ or $v$, not both, is in $D$. In this sense, no vertices in $D$ are neighboring. The maximization problem seeks to maximize $|D|$ and the minimization problem seeks to minimize $|D|$. Are both problems solvable in polynomial time?

Comment: Ask yourself: How does such a set look if $G$ is a bipartite graph? How about if $G$ is not bipartite?

Comment: @Highheath turn the comment into an answer?

Comment: Well, $D$ exists iff $G$ is bipartite, so it only makes sense to consider bipartite graphs for finding maximum/minimum such $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see the following observations on the sets $D$ and $C = V\setminus D$:

Every edge in $E$ contains exactly one node in $D$

$\rightarrow$ Every edge in $E$ contains exactly one node in $C$

$\rightarrow$ Both $D$ and $C$ are vertex covers of $G$

$\rightarrow$ Both $D$ and $C$ are independent sets (the complement of a vertex cover is always an independent set)

$\rightarrow (D,C)$ is a 2-coloring of $V$, and as such, they only exist if $G$ is bipartite.

As Michal says in the other answer: If $G$ is connected, then the 2-coloring is unique and can be found in polynomial time.

Even if $G$ is not connected, maximizing the size of such a vertex cover is equal to taking the union of the biggest color class in each component, and can be found quickly as well.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the problem only partially (in particular, for the minimization)
Whether or not the set $D$ exists is equivalent to the fact that $G$ is bipartite. This can be tested in polynomial time.

To see the equivalence, note that $G$ is bipartite if and only if it does not contain an odd cycle. If $G$ is bipartite, each partition is a valid independent vertex cover. On the other hand, if $G$ is not bipartite, then consider the odd cycle $C$ of length $2n+1$ in $G$. Every independent set in $C$ is of size at most $n$, but every vertex cover is of size at least $n+1$, so no such set can exist for $G$.

Suppose that $G$ is conencted, otherwise do it per connected component.

We know that if $G$ is connected then the bipartition is, up to swapping the parts, unique and the minimum independent vertex cover is the smaller of the two parts.

Comment: You should add a proof to the equivalence with the fact that $G$ is bipartite.

Comment: @Highheath If my understanding is correct, finding a 2-coloring solves both problems.